# keras.utils.plot_model keeps telling me to install pydot and graphviz

Tags: python, keras

I tried at least 5 different solutions from numerous posts online but to no avail. This is where I'm at:

In my conda virtual environment, I installed pydot, pydotplus, and graphviz via conda. I went to https://www2.graphviz.org/Packages/stable/windows/10/ and installed both cmake and msbuild and added both /bin folders to User PATH and System PATH variables. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling packages with conda and with pip yet upon running

```
keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model_test.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

I still get this error message:

**('Failed to import pydot. You must `pip install pydot` and install graphviz (https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/), ', 'for `pydotprint` to work.')**

I am able to import pydot and graphviz individually via

```
import pydot
import graphviz
```

I'm not entirely sure what's the issue here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laptop went to sleep overnight and now it's working. Just had to modify the command

```
keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model_test.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

to

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model_test.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

On Mac:

```
pip install pydot 
pip install graphviz
```

wasn't sufficient.

I had to do a -

```
brew install graphviz
```